# Use .so in python

Tags: python, shared-libraries

I just bought a SDK for a device that brings a .so file and a bunch of .h files

The main .h basically has a lot of static methods.

As far as I understood I can load shared objects to python using ctype and cdll unfortunately I am not being able to call any functions...

here's my code so far:

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('mysofile.so')
```

Now I have a Xpto class inside the my .so but I am unable to find out how to call it and/or it's methods...

Answer (score 0):

To get more information, try first:

```
lib.__doc__
dir(lib)
```

If the class isn't intended to be used with Python:
To use a c-class in Python: Try pyste from boost.
See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/python/pyste/doc/introduction.html

With this, you should be able to use the class in python.